# I am new to Kubernetes and want to understand if this agent will be able to mess up my cluster somehow

Tags: kubernetes, cloud

Recently I was searching for ways to reduce cloud bill and came up to a company named `CAST.AI`.

So to run a savings report you need to install their agent to your cluster and they claim it is `read-only`.

How do I check if this is true?

This comes from the [yaml file they provide](https://pastebin.com/pLbYAEGP) (too long to paste whole manifest here)

Comment: Welcome to the community! You shared only `deployment`, but I already can see that it refers to `serviceAccountName: castai-agent`. Please edit your answer and include `role` and `role-binding` to make sure it will be linked to each other.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, sorry. Where would I check that? At the moment I pasted what curl returned from code snippet that would install their agent but I did not proceed yet.

Comment: there should be more resources. For instance `serviceAccount` or `secret`. I'm not familiar with this installation and on their docs it's not clear where all resources come from, however it has to be a long `yaml` file or separate files. How do they suggest installing it? Did they provide a link and suggested running `kubectl apply -f https://blablabla` ?

Comment: Adding the example how it should look like. This is installation process of [k8s CNI flunnel](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel#deploying-flannel-manually). And more important part is [manifest](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml). You can see that it contains multiple resources like `PodSecurityPolicy`, `ClusterRole` and etc. Can be found under `Kind`. Your installation should have something similar. In order to asnwer your question we need `role`/`clusterrole` and `rolebinding` or `clusterrolebinding`.

Comment: ah you are right, the snipped I pasted was cut off. I edited my question to have full yaml file now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Based on `cast.io` manifest **it's indeed `read-only` and safe to say it won't mess up anything in the cluster**

### Detailed answer

In short words manifest will create: namespace, serviceaccount, clusterole with read-only permissions, clusterrolebinding (where mapping between service account and cluster role happens), secret and deployment with pod which will collect cluster's data.

`ClusterRole` means that service account linked to this `ClusterRole` will have access with given verbs within **all namespaces** (which is fine for resource audit).

Below is `ClusterRole` from manifest (added several comments at the beginning, structure is the same):

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: castai-agent
  labels:
    "app.kubernetes.io/name": castai-agent
rules:
  # ---
  # Required for cost savings estimation features.
  # ---
  - apiGroups: # api group to look in
    - ""
    resources: # resources where this ClusterRole will have access to
      - pods
      - nodes
      - replicationcontrollers
      - persistentvolumeclaims
      - persistentvolumes
      - services
    verbs: # what this cluster role is allowed to do
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
    - "apps"
    resources:
      - deployments
      - replicasets
      - daemonsets
      - statefulsets
    verbs: # what this cluster role is allowed to do with resources above
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
    - "storage.k8s.io"
    resources:
      - storageclasses
      - csinodes
    verbs: # what this cluster role is allowed to do
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
    - "batch"
    resources:
      - jobs
    verbs: # what this cluster role is allowed to do
      - get
      - list
      - watch
```

All actions that `ClusterRole` is allowed to perform are: `get`, `list` and `watch` which are harmless.

Here is a list of all available verbs:

- get
- list
- create
- update
- patch
- watch
- delete
- deletecollection

[list of all available attributes, including verbs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#review-your-request-attributes)

### Resources and limits

Worst case scenario `cast.io` pod will consume resources by its limit (this part in deployment), however with today's clusters it shouldn't be an issue:

```
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 100m
          memory: 64Mi
        limits:
          cpu: 1000m
          memory: 256Mi
```

**Requests** means that this amount of resources are required for `kubelet` to run this pod on the node.

**Limits** as it's named limits maximum possible resources allocation for pod. If it tries to consume more, it will be evicted and rescheduled again to be created.

**Useful links:**

- [Kubernetes RBAC - Role Base Access Control](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)
- [Kubernetes autorization overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/)
- [Resources and limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits)

Comment: thank you for your answer, this was very helpful! tried to upvote but I don't have reputation